# How to identify merge conflicts in submodule references before doing a merge?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to build a script to handle merge conflicts automatically under certain conditions.
I find it challenging to identify merge conflicts in submodule references without doing a merge.

I mean, I would like to find a simple way to identify merge conflicts in submodule references between two branches before doing the merge (even if it is not committed).

When I say submodule references, I don't mean conflicts within the submodule. Rather what I mean can be explained in an example that if the submodule in branch A (in my parent repository) is pointing to reference X and the same submodule in branch B (in my parent repository) is pointing to reference Y. This will cause a conflict if the submodule reference was updated in both branches and it looks like this in SourceTree:

[image: Example of submodule reference conflicts and no conflicts]

As you can see, one submodule reference PNG_ND_Drivers does not have a conflict, and the other one EmbeddedSW_UnitTests, does have a conflict. The changes appear to be of the same nature. There is no way to identify from the changes in the files that there is a conflict. So how can I identify it before doing a merge?

Note: I can do a merge with the --no-commit flag and then review the status of the files using git status --short and find under

> Unmerged paths:
>             both modified:   EmbeddedSW-UnitTests

whereas the other submodule appears under:

> Changes not staged for commit:   
>             modified:   PNG_ND_Drivers (new commits)

So I could identify the conflict this way. But I would need to do the merge and then abort and discard it. It seems too cumbersome, so I wanted to ask if someone knows of a way to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Lucas Oshiro did provide a general methodology for finding conflicts in submodules, I prefer to use a more simpler approach with `git merge-tree --write-tree` that does not require mentioning any submodule name and requires fewer commands:

```bash
# Define the branches
origin_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
destination_branch="origin/main"
    
# Perform the merge-tree command and capture the output
merge_output=$(git merge-tree --write-tree --name-only $origin_branch $destination_branch)
    
# Extract submodule names with conflicts from the merge output using grep and store in an array
mapfile -t conflicted_submodules < <(echo "$merge_output" | grep -E '^CONFLICT.*submodule' | awk '{print $NF}')
    
# Display the list of submodule conflicts
echo "Conflicts found in the following submodules:"
printf '%s\n' "${conflicted_submodules[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to understand how Git Merge works. When we merge two branches `A` and `B`, Git will perform a three-way merge for each file. Basically, it works like that:

1. If the file has the same content on both branches, it will be used in the merge commit
2. If the content of the file on branch `A` is the same of the content on the common ancestor between `A` and `B`, then the content in `B` will be used in the merge commit
3. If the content of the file on branch `B` is the same of the content on the common ancestor between `A` and `B`, then the content in `A` will be used in the merge commit
4. If the content of the file on `A`, `B` and on the common ancestor between `A` and `B` is different, then we have a conflict. If it's a plaintext file, then Git will try to merge internally if the changes don't conflict.

This is also what Git does when merging submodules, but instead of comparing the content of a file, it compares the commit that the submodule points to on each branch and the common ancestor. So, you can check it manually:

1. `git rev-parse A:path_to_submodule` and `git rev-parse B:path_to_submodule` will return the hash of the commit that the submodule points to on `A` and `B` (the hashes of `X` and `Y` in your example). If they are the same, then you don't have a conflict
2. `git merge-base A B` will give you the hash of the common ancestor between `A` and `B`
3. `git rev-parse <hash from step 2>:path_to_submodule` will return the hash of the commit that the submodule points to on the common ancestor. Compare it with the two hashes from step 1. If it is different from both, then you have a conflict

This may work:

```bash
x=$(git rev-parse A:path_to_submodule)
y=$(git rev-parse B:path_to_submodule)
common=$(git merge-base A B)
z=$(git rev-parse $common:path_to_submodule)
[ "$x" != "$y" ] && [ "$z" != "$x" ] && [ "$z" != "$y" ]
conflict=$?
```

If want to read more about it, I wrote this text explaining how Git merges submodules: https://lucasoshiro.github.io/posts-en/2022-03-12-merge-submodule/, I hope it helps you!